# Weird raycasting issues

Tags: javascript

i have been working on a javascript raycaster recently as a little side project. i have been having some troubles with textures. the texture look all weird and scrambled. i have been implementing bits and pieces of a tutorial series as well.

[image: walls look all weird]

https://github.com/vinibiavatti1/RayCastingTutorial/wiki

please excuse my terrible code

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var angle_rad;
var t;
var height = 0;
let collide;
let downPressed;
let upPressed;
let rightPressed;
let leftPressed;
var TILE = {
  t: 0,
  x: 0,
  y: 0

}

ctx.lineWidth = 3.5;

var map = {

  cols: 8,
  rows: 8,
  tsize: 32,
  tiles: [
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
  ],
  getTile: function(col, row) {
    return this.tiles[row * map.cols + col];
  }
}

var player = {
  speed: 1,
  angle: 0,
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  dx: 0,
  dy: 0,
  fx: 0,
  fy: 0,
  drawPlayer: function() {

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 1, 1);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

//ray
var ray = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  d: 0,
  collide: false
}

// delcare scale data or some thing
const texture = {
  width: 8,
  height: 8,
  bitmap: [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
  ],
  colors: [
    "#ff0000",
    "#ffffff",
  ]

}

// function to draw map
function drawmap() {
  for (var column = 0; column < map.cols; column++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < map.rows; row++) {
      const tile = map.getTile(column, row);
      const x = column * map.tsize;
      const y = row * map.tsize;
      if (tile === 0) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(x, y, 32, 32);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      //detect collision and prevent it

      if (tile === 1 || tile === 2) {
        if (player.x > x && player.x < x + map.tsize && player.y > y && player.y < y + map.tsize) {

          collide = true;
        } else {
          collide = false;
        }


      }

    }
  }
}


// do stuff when key press and not pressed
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key === "Right" || e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.key === "Left" || e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
  if (e.key === "Up" || e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    upPressed = true;
  } else if (e.key === "Down" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    downPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.key === "Right" || e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.key === "Left" || e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
  if (e.key === "Up" || e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    upPressed = false;
  } else if (e.key === "Down" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    downPressed = false;
  }
}

// loop
setInterval(loop, 10);

//move player fucntion
function move() {

  angle_rad = player.angle * Math.PI / 180;

  if (upPressed) {
    player.x += player.speed * Math.sin(angle_rad);
    player.y -= player.speed * Math.cos(angle_rad);

  }
  if (leftPressed) {
    player.angle += 2;
  } else if (rightPressed) {
    player.angle -= 2;
  }
}

function raycast(a) {
  console.log(ray.x);
  ray.x = player.x;
  ray.y = player.y;

  for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
      for (let r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
        let type = map.getTile(c, r);
        let TX = c * map.tsize;
        let TY = r * map.tsize;

        if (type === 1) {
          if (ray.x > TX && ray.x < TX + map.tsize && ray.y > TY && ray.y < TY + map.tsize) {
            ray.x += Math.sin(a);
            ray.y -= Math.cos(a);
          } else {

          }
        }
      }
    }



  }
}




//loop function
function loop() {

  //log distance





  //clear prevoius mess
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 256);
  drawmap();
  move();

  for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    //get distance
    ray.d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(player.x - ray.x, 2) + Math.pow(player.y - ray.y, 2));
    height = Math.floor(1000 / ray.d);

    let tex_X = Math.floor((texture.width * (ray.x + ray.y)) % texture.width);

    raycast(angle_rad + ((i * Math.PI / 180)) - 45);
    ray.d = ray.d * Math.cos((angle_rad + ((i * Math.PI / 180)) - 45) - angle_rad);

    drawline(i * 3 + 300, 0, i * 3 + 300, 126 - height, "cyan");
    drawTexture(i * 3 + 300, height, tex_X, texture);
    drawline(i * 3 + 300, 126 + height, i * 3 + 300, 256, "green")


  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ray.x, ray.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();



  player.drawPlayer();

}

//draw line function
function drawline(x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.stroke();
}
//draw textured wall function
function drawTexture(x, wall_height, tex_posX, tex) {
  let yinc = (wall_height * 2) / tex.height;
  let y = 126 - wall_height;

  for (let i = 0; i < tex.height; i++) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = tex.colors[tex.bitmap[i][tex_posX]];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + (yinc + 0.5));
    ctx.stroke();
    y += yinc;
  }
}

// listen for kep press and key downs
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="256" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: Please add some images/screenshots of what you are seeing

Comment: And it would be great if you could format your code :)